# how to Magento sending SMS upon creating shipment

Tags: magento, sms

Magento sending SMS when order confirmed and creating shipment, we have PHP code below:

```
   <?php 
$ch = curl_init(); 
$user="**@bindaaslo.com:**"; 
$receipientno="98910***"; 
$senderID="TEST SMS"; 
$msgtxt="this is test message , test"; curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt"); $buffer = curl_exec($ch); if(empty ($buffer)) { echo " buffer is empty "; } else { echo $buffer; } curl_close($ch); 
   ?>
```

Comment: This extension already has shipment notification for admin and customers both https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

open file `[magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php`

find saveAction() and add your code in that

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        ......................

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        $user="**@bindaaslo.com:**"; 
        $receipientno="98910***"; 
        $senderID="TEST SMS"; 
        $msgtxt="this is test message , test"; curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt"); $buffer = curl_exec($ch); if(empty ($buffer)) { echo " buffer is empty "; } else { echo $buffer; } curl_close($ch); 

        ......................
    }
```

**Note: Don't directly change in core files instead of it override controller.**

**Or**

you can achieve same through **observer**

some links help you to create observer for sales_order_shipment_save_before events

[Magento - 2 or more observer on same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491813/magento-2-or-more-observer-on-same-event)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/847/hook-into-order-shipped-event-and-get-order-id-for-order-shipped